# use validateRequired through composite component

Tags: jsf-2, facelets, composite-component

I'm trying to forward "f:validateRequired" validator through a composite component without using required attribute.

How to get its value inside of my component ?

```
<aa:myComponent id="specificNotice" value="#{edit.specificNotice}">
        <f:validateRequired for="specificNotice" disabled="#{empty param['form:save']}" />
    </aa:myComponent>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The `for` attribute should refer the `id` of the input component inside the composite component implementation. The input component in turn should be declared as [`<cc:editableValueHolder>`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/composite/editableValueHolder.html) inside the composite component interface.

So,

```
<my:input value="#{bean.input}">
    <f:validateRequired for="input" />
</my:input>
```

with

```
<cc:interface>
    <cc:editableValueHolder name="input" />
</cc:interface>
<cc:implementation>
    <h:inputText id="input" value="#{cc.attrs.value}" />
</cc:implementation>
```

should do.